# Plastic sun blocking curtain ("pulldown") for glass doors?

Tags: doors

I have reflective UV / sun blocking coverings for the windows of my home. They're fantastic for blocking the sun since it's blasted during the day AND offers great privacy during the day. They're basically two way mirrors during the day.

I have a glass storm door that we'd like to do something similar with, but sometimes we don't want to block the view. (Ie, night time warrants seeing through it and so do cloudy days, etc.)

Are there any such options that would offer a plastic or polymer based two way mirror curtain that can be pulled down and put up at will? Have had no luck hunting down such a solution as of yet...

If nothing like this exists, would it be something that can be built? I realize it would be pretty tricky, but perhaps something like vinyl blinds made of such a material would work.

Comment: Are you planning to mount it to the storm door?

Comment: Yes @ChrisM., I'd like to mount it at the top of the metal door.